# Close/Open circuit based on power supply to a relay

Tags: relay, dc-motor, solid-state-relay, ac-dc, toggle-switch

I am new here and to electrical world. I need to resolve a very basic real life issue. I have two fans in my bed room. One is AC and the other one DC powered by a lead acid battery. I want the DC fan to start automatically when there is electricity outage and stop otherwise. Can I do it with some kind of relay in between DC circuit to DC fan?
I mean to fix a relay that keeps the DC fan's circuit open as long as AC power is supplied to the relay and closes it otherwise.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: What kind of relay should I use ?

Comment: Question should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: search of ask for an appropriate voltage ac coil relay

Comment: I did research but couldn't found anything helpful, may be because of my little or no knowledge of electronics.

Comment: Where do you live.. whats your AC voltage?

Comment: 220 volts, 50 Hertz

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/relays/power-relays-over-2-amps/188?k=ac+relay&k=&pkeyword=ac+relay&pv72=32&FV=ffe000bc&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25 you need to know the DC voltage and amps you need to switch too

Comment: Once you settle on the requirements you can probably find a cheaper one on -e-bay or somewhere though.

Comment: Drive your relay coil with a walwart or USB charger no need to run it at mains voltage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a normally closed (also called form B) relay or a SPDT (single pole, double throw) relay with an appropriate AC coil. The coil of the relay must be rated for your household power - 220 V at 50 Hertz - and connected to your AC mains. The relay will normally be energized when your AC power is working. When the power goes out, the relay will no longer be energized. At this point the "normally closed" contacts on the relay will be like a switch that turns on. These contacts can be used to turn on your DC fan. When the AC power is restored, these contacts will open, again turning off your DC fan.

The contacts for the relay must be rated to at least handle the current that your DC fan draws.

You can find a basic, animated description of how relays work [here](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/howrelayswork.html).